# Regexp to fit unordered list

Tags: java, regex

I have a lot of strings in which are stored values like:

```
(40|21|33)(111|222|333)(1|2)
```

As you can see above - there are three groups, each group consists of one or more values of constant length, but values in given group can occur in any order (it is not defined if it is ascending or descending).

I am looking through groups of values using regular expressions and I stuck on method which purpose is to detect if a group of values (i.e. `20 or 31`) exists in given group (i.e. `(40|21|33)`).

I have made regex which detects if there is **ANY** of values of i.e. `20 or 31`, but it should fit only when there are **ALL** of values specified:

```
(\()([0-9]{2}(\|)?)*((20(\|)?)|(31(\|)?))([0-9]{2}(\|)?)*(\))
```

Is there a way to detect if in given group are **ALL** of given values, assuming that order of values in a group is unknown?

*Just to clarify*

```
(40|31|20) - should fit since there are all values of search group (20,31)
(40|22|20) - should not fit since there is only one value of search group (20,31)
```

Comment: either you are not very clear or i am too dumb to understand your question

Comment: @aelor done little edit, maybe this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\(               # Match (
(?=[^()]*\b21\b) # Assert that 21 can be matched within this group
(?=[^()]*\b33\b) # Assert that 33 can be matched within this group
\d+              # Match a number    
(?:              # Start of non-capturing group:
 \|              #  Match |
 \d+             #  Match a number
)*               # any number of times, including 0
\)               # Match )
```

or, in Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\\(                # Match (\n" +
    "(?=[^()]*\\b21\\b) # Assert that 21 can be matched within this group\n" +
    "(?=[^()]*\\b33\\b) # Assert that 33 can be matched within this group\n" +
    "\\d+               # Match a number    \n" +
    "(?:                # Start of non-capturing group:\n" +
    " \\|               #  Match |\n" +
    " \\d+              #  Match a number\n" +
    ")*                 # any number of times, including 0\n" +
    "\\)                # Match )", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lM2kB6).